# Contribution Page Include Profile Dropdown not displayed

Tags: profile, contribution-page

I am relatively new to CiviCRM and it is really great.

But now i came to the first problem, which i am not able to solve.

I want to include profiles to a contribution page and in the documentation it says there should be a dropdown box but in my case there is no dropdown as you can see on the image. I already tried to delete the cache as suggested in another post. But that didnt work neither.

Can someone help me? Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Greetings and thanks in advance 
Max

[image]

Comment: Can you please state what version of CiviCRM you are using and which CMS you are using? That will certainly help with this issue. I can see the dropdown box on the latest demo site, so it is possibly an issue with your specific configuration....and explaining your configuration will help.

Comment: Hey thanks for the fast reply

I am using Wordpress 4.3.1, CiviCrm 4.6, MySQL 5.5.40, PHP 5.6.12

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by deactivating several plugins

its probably a javascript problem

Thanks