# How to enable profiles in Contribution Pages?

Tags: profile, contributions

In my contribution pages, I cannot see the Profile dropdown. Is there a way to enable this?

I have disabled all of my plugins and changed my theme to 2016 to see if it's an error on my side. So far no dice.

I'm using 4.7.1 for Wordpress.

[image: Tis is what I see for profiles in all of my contribution pages]

Comment: Which profiles are enabled on your site?

Comment: Similar to this question http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7827/contribution-page-include-profile-dropdown-not-displayed

Comment: That post indicated the problem related to plugins. You say you have yours turned off. But it may be a js error.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to quick replies. You were right- I overlooked a plugin. On my site, it was the Ultimate Addon for Visual Composer.

As long as it's disabled, I can see the Profile selector. Once I'm done, I can enable the plugin and not loose functionality on the front of the site.